# How to get Android Context for Koin in Java

Tags: java, android, koin

I want to get AndroidContext for Koin in Java.
In Kotlin I would call androidContext() in startKoin block
https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/dsl/

But in Java I start Koin in this way

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        KoinApplication koin = KoinAndroidApplication
                .create(this)
                .modules(KoinInjectorKt.getKoinInjector());
        startKoin(koin);
    }
}
```

and I there is no androidContext() function in `KoinAndroidApplication`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to KDoc

```
KoinAndroidApplication.create(..) 

Create Koin Application with Android context - For Java compat
```

It's already using `androidContext` under the hood(when you call `KoinAndroidApplication.create(this)` ), if you open sources of the `KoinAndroidApplication` you will see:

```
object KoinAndroidApplication {

    /**
     * Create Koin Application with Android context - For Java compat
     */
    @JvmStatic
    @JvmOverloads
    fun create(context: Context, androidLoggerLevel: Level = Level.INFO): KoinApplication {
        return KoinApplication.init().androidContext(context).androidLogger(androidLoggerLevel)
    }
}
```